# Accessing system enums in WPF datatemplates

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, xaml, datatemplate

I'm trying to add a data trigger for a property called 'Status' in my own class of type ServiceControllerStatus (an enum found in System.ServiceProcess).

I added this to the XAML:

```
xmlns:System="clr-namespace:System.ServiceProcess;assembly=System.ServiceProcess.dll"
```

And am trying to use data triggers based on the value of 'Status' by doing this:

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Status}" >
    <DataTrigger.Value>                             
        <System:ServiceControllerStatus>Running</System:ServiceControllerStatus>
    </DataTrigger.Value>
    <Setter TargetName="border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="Green"/>
</DataTrigger>
```

But am receiving an error "The tag 'ServiceControllerStatus' does not exist in XML namespace 'clr-namespace:System.ServiceProcess;assembly=System.ServiceProcess.dll"

Is it possible to use enums defined in system namespaces, or must you only reference enums defined in your own classes?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use enum with the `{x:Static}` form.

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Status}" 
             Value="{x:Static System:ServiceControllerStatus.Running}">
    <Setter TargetName="border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="Green"/>
</DataTrigger>
```

**UPDATE:**

don't use .dll extension string in assembly statement.

`assembly=System.ServiceProcess.dll` -> `assembly=System.ServiceProcess`

```
xmlns:System="clr-namespace:System.ServiceProcess;assembly=System.ServiceProcess"
```

PS: I'm not good at English.

Comment: @Shaun remove `.dll`. then you can compile.